Optimization of Calibration Periodicity for Temperature Instruments
I am currently working on a project to optimize the calibration periodicity of instruments in an electronics industry. My instruments involve temperature measurements (oven, incubator, probe, etc.).
I have identified two possible methods to determine this periodicity: the drift method and the Opperet method. However, being an intern during the summer, the Opperet method seems difficult to implement without a team of experts.
I am wondering if the drift method, although often used for dimensional instruments, can be adapted for my temperature instruments. During the calibration of the oven, the laboratory installed 9 temperature sensors and recorded the minimum and maximum values. Which value should I take to apply this drift method optimally?
I would appreciate any advice on the most appropriate method and any detailed documents on calculating calibration periodicity.
Thank you for your help.

You should start with a simple "default" method. Then you can compare of the performance of other methods against that.
